# why Train/Test-split in ML?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, train-test-split

I can't understand why we need to split dataset in machine learning. And why this train-test-split algorithm gives four parameters(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)?

I see many videos and read some blogs, they explain a lot of reasons. No one agree with each other. Is there any common reason to use this algorithm?

Comment: Please note that this question is off-topic, ML methodology is not a programming problem and/or question and should not be answered in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

> I see many videos and read some blogs, they explain a lot of reasons. No one agree with each other.

There are not "a lot of reasons". (If you find so, it would help to summarise your understanding on what these "lot of reasons" are, so we can address them.)

> why Train/Test-split in ML?

When you test the model you want to test its *predictive power*, not the power of *memorisation*.

Imagine a meteorologist who went to the university for years and years in order to only be correct on what the weather was *yesterday* (because he has seen it happen). Imagine a doctor who can't diagnose any people correctly, except those who come with a medical chart with diagnosis someone else already made. Imagine a student of mathematics who can only add two numbers together if he was taught to add those specific two numbers together before: he knows `2+2` and `4+3`, but not `2+3` because no-one showed him the result before.

If you teach someone a topic by example, and only check their understanding by testing on those examples, you are checking for rote memorisation. Even if the test scores are high, they might have no understanding, no generalisation on the topic. It is equivalent to giving students a test after letting them see the answer sheet: the grade has no meaning. You have to test on new examples, *unseen* ones, to accurately check whether the learning produced the capacity to infer the knowledge about the unseen examples from the examples showed in training. You have to teach `2+2=4` and `4+3=7`, and test on `2+3` which you *haven't* taught, to avoid passing students who only remember `2+2=4` and `4+3=7`, and shrug their shoulders when asked about `2+3`, because "the teacher never told them that".

> And why this train-test-split algorithm gives four parameters(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)?

Each example consists of two parts: the question and the answer. `x` is the question part, `y` is the answer. In this simplified example, the teacher will show the students:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2 + 2 | 4 |
| 4 + 3 | 7 |

then give them the test like this:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2 + 3 | _ |

and expect the filled test to be like this:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2 + 3 | 5 |

This gives you the four arrays: `x_train` and `y_train` (the questions and answers you teach), `x_test` (the questions you ask on the test) and `y_test` (the answers you expect on the answer sheet).

Comment: Given your reputation, you should be completely aware of not answering off-topic questions, as this is a ML question and not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

we use train,test split to split the data.
if we don't use it how can we check the performance of the data with the unseen data other than the train data.
train data is used to train the model
test data is used to check the accuracy of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need a train and test data to work with ML models:

- In beginning we build a model on train data [ x_train(independent variables) , y_train( dependent variable )]
- then now our aim is to test model performance on some unknown data i.e., test data here [ x_test , y_test ] then calculate the prediction error / MAPE and conclude whether this model is good fit or not.
- we usually take 70% train and 30% test data.